# Posso inserir registos no SQLite usando PhoneGap?

Tags: apache-cordova

Ambiente do curso

*JDK 7u45 ou superior.

Android SDK 2.3.3 ADT Bundle ou superior.

Apache ant 1.9.2 ou superior.

Node Js 0.10.24 ou superior.

isso são descrições do curso de PhoneGap Mobile da TreinaWeb.*

Eu gostaria de saber se pelo FrameWorks PhoneGap Mobile dá para programar somente em JavaScript, HTML5 e CSS3, Jquery inserindo registros no banco SQLite ou ele é um FrameWorks de utilidade para Front End como é usado nas paginas de internet sendo que esse é voltado para Mobile?

Estou fazendo essa pergunta porque eu pesquisei bastante de como programar Jquery para Mobile e a única coisa que encontrei era tutorial mostrando como criar os botões,telas e e cores sem ser mencionados algoritmos que mostrem como inserir , deletar e atualizar.

Eu conheço um pouco de programação Android, e para mim não é legal ficar trabalhando com XML, mas se eu pudesse substituir o XML pelo JavaScript, HTML5 e CSS3, Jquery seria fantástico.

Comment: Tente por o titulo mais apelativo, mais concreto. Acho que as primeiras linhas não querem dizer nada em relação a pergunta em si, eu apagava. Tente manter as perguntas de forma a apelar a resposta. Edite a sua questão se achar que deve. Eu sugeria o titulo: "Posso inserir registos no SQLite usando PhoneGap?"

Comment: muito obrigado pela dica

Answer (score 1):

Isso mesmo, o Phonegrap(cordova) é um framework onde você pode desenvolver suas aplicações cross-platform usando javascript, html e css. A conexão com banco pode ser feita pelo próprio javascript, como nesse exemplo https://gist.github.com/edwardtoday/2204864

Hoje para desenvolver com essas tecnologias você pode usar o http://ionicframework.com
ele roda encima do cordova também, mas é baseado em angularjs. Muito bom.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, o phonegap trabalha com SQLite, você precisa apenas adicionar o plugin e começar a usar.

Além disso, com a nova API web você pode usar o armazenamento de dados local e ficou mais fácil ainda de manipular dados em seu app.

Maiores informações [aqui](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage).

Para descrição e exemplo de uso, [acesse aqui](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_localstorage_localstorage.md.html).